# Windows is showing rpc server is unavailable when connecting to a SAMBA AD hosted on debian

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

I have set up SAMBA to act as an AD DC and my machine connects to it fine but when I try to find the Active Directory tools from inside my windows machine I get the error 'naming information cannot be located because: the rpc server is unavailable'

I have no idea what thats bout and the few cases ive seen online deal in different situation not applicable to my case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be on either the client or server machine.

Make sure Samba is [listening on the right ports](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_Port_Usage). RPC is on port 135. If you don't see Samba listening on port 135, then that's your problem.

Also make sure that, on your client Windows machine, the "TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper" service is running (in services.msc) and set to run automatically. If that was not running, then that's your problem.